# WordPress Deployment failed using Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

While deploying WordPress in azure,I had met with an Failed Notification specifying the following:

Type:SuccessBricks.ClearDB/databases
Status:Bad Request
Properties: 
statusCode:BadRequest
serviceRequestId:
statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"MissingMarketplacePlanPublisher","message":"The marketplace resource plan is missing required \"publisher\" property."}}

I have tried deploying new wordpress app,but still the same failed message is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deploying it from the classic Azure services manager instead https://manage.windowsazure.com. I was having the same problem. It might be related to your database name. The classic interface required my database name be less than 16 characters, while the Azure portal let me type over that, but failed during deployment.

Also, make sure you're not using a VS MSDN subscription. I don't think you can use your free credits towards ClearDB MySQL. Alternatively, you could install MySQL on a linux server and pay for compute time out of your MSDN subscription.

Edited: FYI, I contacted CloudSQL about the error and received the following:

Thanks for contacting us, and our apologies for the inconvenience. There
currently is an issue that the Azure Marketplace is experiencing that is
causing this to happen. The Azure UI team is aware of the problem and is
working to resolve it today.

Thanks very much for your patience - this should be resolved soon.

Comment: ya ur right..its a technical error..It has been solved..and works now.       Thank you..